# Turing Degree and Local Contest Questions?

Tags: math, computation-theory, turing-machines, computation, computability

I ran into a olympiad question on Practical Computer Knowledge.

> For *A* ⊆ ℕ we have *a* = deg<sub>*T*</sub>(*A*) = {*B* | *B* ≡<sub>*T*</sub> A} and *D* = {deg<sub>*T*</sub>(*A*) | *A* ⊆ ℕ}. For (*D*, ≤) that has A ≤<sub>*T*</sub> *B* iff *a* ≤ *b*. Which of the following is false:
>
> 1. (D,≤) is a distributive lattice
> 2. (D,≤)‌ is bounded (has minimum and maximum)
> 3. (D,≤) is a half disjunctive lattice. (may be I‌ worded this statement poorly, sorry)
> 4. he maximum elements of (D,≤) is a degree of Halting Problem .

I think deg<sub>*T*</sub> means [Turing Degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree) and ≤<sub>*T‌*</sub> means [Turing Reduciblity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction).

Who can give me a hint for these options, we want to check the answer
sheet that wrote (1) is correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a computer science question and not a programming question. It may be more suitable at a different [se] site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41214/halting-problem-and-turing-degree-and-reduction

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does appear about theoretic computer sciences, not programming. The [version at CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/41214/17342) would be better suited. That has been closed, too, but for being unclear, not for being off topic. So editing there to clarify might help getting that reopened. Or perhaps the answers and comments there are already sufficient.